# How to avoid page loading in Angularjs 1.x until dependencies resolved?

Tags: angularjs, security, angular-ui-router, authorization

Sample code snippet

```
module.config(function($stateProvider, $couchPotatoProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('app.securePage', {
     url: '/secure-page',
     views: {
        'foo': {
          controller: 'SecureCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'app/modules/templates/secure-page.html',
          resolve:  {
              deps: $couchPotatoProvider.resolveDependencies([
                  'modules/common/service/Profile',  #Have access to all
                  'modules/common/service/List', #Have access to all
                  'modules/secure/service/Admin' #Restricted access - throws 403 response whenever unauthorized user tries to access 
              ])
          }
       }
      } 
   }) 
})

// In HTTP Interceptor
app.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope, $log, $window) {
    return {
         ...
        responseError: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 403) {
                document.location.href = $rootScope.baseUrl+'/dashboard';
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
})
```

The problem here is, unauthorized users getting secure url from somewhere and trying to access the page but initially template is loading after a second we redirecting to some other page. Here I want to avoid loading template until all dependencies resolved.

Comment: You can secure template on backend.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Is it? I'm not aware this, I'll check for this option.